# Linux auto chown web uploaded files to users folders

Tags: permissions, chmod, upload, chown

I have a home server that stores my files and I access the files in my internal network with samba. I have 3 users and each user has its home folder on /home/user.

In order to access the files from outside, I'm using a web based file explorer. The file explorer can login into these 3 user accounts and see the data, because I set the /home/user folder permissions to 770 and added the wwwrun user to the group of the desired user.

For example, the user John home folder is /home/john and this folder is owned by john:john with permissions 770. The john group contains users john and wwwrun.

The problem is when I upload any file via the web file explorer. I can upload the files to /home/john folder, but the file ownership is wwwrun:john. I want the upload files to be automatically owned as john:john with permissions 770.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing the
[setgid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#SGID)
functionality, where when a directory that has it set will force any new file
created within it to have their group set to the same group that's set on the
parent directory.

To make **new** files inherit the group of the container folder do:

```
$ chmod g+s thefolder
```